# Handling escape sequence in query params in rails app server with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-like

```
query_string = params[:q]
model.where("name ILIKE ? ", "#{query_string}").limit(10)
```

In the controller I have the above lines

`params[:q]` is the user input.

Whenever the user input ends with `\`, say `police \`, Postgres throws this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::InvalidEscapeSequence: ERROR:  LIKE pattern must not end with escape character.
```

How can we gracefully handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different escape character, for example:

```
WHERE name ILIKE 'pattern\' ESCAPE '/'
```

If you have no safe escape character, you can double it:

```
WHERE nane ILIKE replace('pattern\', '\', '\\')
```

Comment: Nope then if the user enters 'Police /' I will be getting the same error right?
params[:q]  is a user input.

Comment: how can gracefully handle all such cases?

Comment: Double the escape character as indicated in the extended answer.

Comment: if I use replace then in valid cases like 'police \a ' it will get queried as 'police \\a' isn't it? Isn't that not desirable??

But chances that I get input like 'police \a ' is minimal so I might as well use this, but still wondering..

Comment: Well, if the backslash sometimes is an escape character and sometimes not, you need to have additional information. There is no way to guess which is meant.

Comment: In the rails controller when I have this

exact_entries =  model.where("name ILIKE replace( ?, '\', '\\') ", "#{query_string}").limit(10)

the query gets fired as 
 WHERE (name ILIKE replace( 'police\', '', '\') ) LIMIT 10

Uff...

Comment: That's probably Rails, and you have to double the backslashes there.